# Quantikz draw kink on wire

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-cd, quantikz

I want to draw a kink on a wire using [`quantikz`](https://ctan.org/pkg/quantikz). I'm using the second block of code on p.14 of the quantikz docs,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsfonts,dsfont}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{quantikz}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}

\begin{quantikz}
& \gate{H} & \ctrl{2} & \ \ldots\ \qw & \qw & \gate{H} & \qw \\
& \gate{H} & \qw & \ \ldots\ \qw & \ctrl{1} & \gate{H} & \qw \\
& \qw & \gate{U} & \arrow[dashed, "z" marking]{r} & \gate{U} & \qw
\end{quantikz}

\end{document}
```

I tried using `\arrow[]{}` from tikzcd to draw something like

[image]

but I can't seem to get the zigzag marking on the wire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I use a `path picture` with a `zigzag` line. Any other path can also be drawn.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\usetikzlibrary{quantikz}
\tikzset{
zigstyle/.style={
draw=none,
path picture={\draw[decoration={zigzag, pre length=\pgflinewidth, post length=\pgflinewidth}, decorate] (path picture bounding box.west) -- (path picture bounding box.east);}
}}
\begin{document}
\begin{quantikz}
& \gate{H} & \ctrl{2} & \ \ldots\ \qw                    & \qw      & \gate{H} & \qw \\
& \gate{H} & \qw      & \ \ldots\ \qw                    & \ctrl{1} & \gate{H} & \qw \\
& \qw      & \gate{U} & \gate[style={zigstyle}][0.6cm]{} & \gate{U} & \qw
\end{quantikz}
\end{document}
```

[image: Cumulative diagram with lines and a zigzag]

Edit: With a single zig-zag:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{quantikz}
\tikzset{
zigstyle/.style={
draw=none,
path picture={\draw (path picture bounding box.west) -- +(1pt,0) -- ++(5pt,5pt) -- ++(2pt,-10pt) -- ++(5pt,5pt) -- (path picture bounding box.east);}
}}
\begin{document}
    \begin{quantikz}
    & \gate{H} & \ctrl{2} & \ \ldots\ \qw                    & \qw      & \gate{H} & \qw \\
    & \gate{H} & \qw      & \ \ldots\ \qw                    & \ctrl{1} & \gate{H} & \qw \\
    & \qw      & \gate{U} & \gate[style={zigstyle}][0.4cm]{} & \gate{U} & \qw
    \end{quantikz}
    \end{document}
```

[image: Cumulative diagram with lines and zigzag]

Answer (score 1):

A zigzag line isn't hard to draw with TikZ, though I don't know how to use it inside `quantikz` without it adding a `\qw`s after the `\gate` (which draws a line back to the left).

Here I added another `\qw` to the `\dots` column so that the zigzag marking is at least consistently on top of a line.

Add the key `arrows` to the options of `\arrow[rr, -, zigzag marking]` so that it inherits the same style as all lines in the `quantikz`.

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{quantikz}
\tikzset{
  zigzag marking/.default=1ex,
  zigzag marking/.style={
    to path={% no \tikztonodes
      -- ($(\tikztostart)!.5!(\tikztotarget)!#1!(\tikztostart)$)
      -- ($(\tikztostart)!.5!(\tikztotarget)!#1!90:(\tikztostart)$)
      -- ($(\tikztostart)!.5!(\tikztotarget)!#1!270:(\tikztostart)$)
      -- ($(\tikztostart)!.5!(\tikztotarget)!#1!(\tikztotarget)$)
      -- (\tikztotarget)
    }
  }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{quantikz}
& \gate{H} & \ctrl{2}                               & \ \ldots\ \qw & \qw      & \gate{H} & \qw \\
& \gate{H} & \qw                                    & \ \ldots\ \qw & \ctrl{1} & \gate{H} & \qw \\
& \qw      & \gate{U} \arrow[rr, -, zigzag marking] &           \qw & \gate{U} & \qw
\end{quantikz}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]